# Compiling C/C++ for an old Ubuntu version in a newer Ubuntu version

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling

I have build servers that run Ubuntu 18.04 (in a Docker container), but I need to build binaries (various static and shared libraries and executables) for older versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 16.04), without having to install an older version of the OS.

Currently we use sysroot toolchains (that include compiler and libraries etc) and CMake toolchain files for building for other targets (e.g. ARM Poky/Yocto), and it would be ideal if we could use the same approach for building for older (or potentially newer) versions of Ubuntu.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Anything is possible, but the easiest thing you can do is create a new Docker image (or some other type of machine) with an older OS on it.  Then everything will "just work."

If you really don't want to do that, you need to identify all the dependencies, starting with libc, which have symbols missing on the older platform, then figure out how to avoid using those symbols.  This will probably waste a ton of time, especially considering you already have one build container (making a second one shouldn't be hard).

Comment: That is certainly a solution that will take care of all potential problems, and it's also one that I've considered. However, the way it's set up today (for various reasons) we would have to dedicate each build machine to a specific Docker container, which is not desirable (waste of HW). Being able to use a "16.04 toolchain" in a 18.04 container would therefore be ideal (since we already have a system for that in place).